# Reached home safely or got home safely

Tags: word-choice

If I want to let a person know (anyone, not just family or friends, sometimes even colleagues) that I got home safely. Which verb is correct?

> I **reached** home safely

or

> I **got** home safely.

I think both is correct as both gives the same meaning, except when delivering it to people’s. If not how does it differ?

Comment: What does "*delivering it to people's*" mean? Delivering what? To people's what?

Comment: I meant in plural form peoples.

Comment: *Got home safely* is most common in the U.S.  *Reached home safely* is how a team scores a run in baseball - *A runner reaches home safely.*

Comment: In that case, which tense would you suggest?

Comment: @Blessie It's still not clear. What does "delivering it to peoples" mean? Delivering what? "People" is already the plural of "person". Why pluralize it again?

Comment: What I meant was, if this the  appropriate way to deliver to elderly people as the same like I reached home safely or I got home safely

Answer (score 1):

"Got home" is a little more casual, and so probably the best choice.

There is no difference in tense.  "Reached" and "Got" are both past tense.

I don't know what you mean by "except when delivering it to people's".  But delivery doesn't affect word choice here.

Comment: I've corrected the word "tense" to "verb", so you may want to reword your answer

Comment: Why,  how did you know the OP didn't mean to write "tense"?

Comment: Because both examples are in the simple past, and the only difference between the two answers was the verb choice

Comment: I know that.  Does the OP know that?  The OP asked about tense.  Isn't it possible that they wanted to know about tense?  It might have been better to clarify with the OP in comments instead of editing.

Answer (score 1):

"I **got** home safely" is the most common way to say you've gotten home safely, at least in North America.

"I **reached** home safely" could describe the same situation, but the focus with "reach" is on how far you made it, as if you weren't sure how far you would get, but you made it the whole way home. Again, this is true in North America.

I have a feeling Brits use "reach" and "arrive" naturally in this context.